# jQuery sortable: changing cursor on mousedown and up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a basic jQuery sortable list that works fine, but I'm now trying to change the cursor to a closed hand on mousedown event.

The first attempt at a drag results in only the cursor changing to closedhand -- the element does not drag.
Subsequent drags work fine: the element drags and cursor changes to closed hand and back to open hand onmouseup.

If I click the mouse once before attempting drag, everything works: drag and cursor change

```
  li:hover { 
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur);  
  }

  .grabbed:hover { 
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur); 
  }
 .grabbed{ 
    cursor: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/closedhand.cur); 
  }      

 //---

    <ol class="sortable">
        <li>grab 0 hereI'm 0!</li>
        <li>grab 1 hereI'm 1!</li>
        <li>grab 2 hereI'm 2!</li>
    </ol>     

  //---


    $('.sortable').sortable();
    $('.sortable').disableSelection();


    $('.sortable').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    });
    $('.sortable').disableSelection();


    $('.sortable').on("mousedown", "li", function(){
        $(this).addClass('grabbed');
        console.log("MOUSE DOWN");
    });

    $('.sortable').on("mouseup", "li",function(){
         $(this).removeClass('grabbed');
         console.log("MOUSE UP");
     });
```

Comment: I think I found the problem; will post an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it: instead of having css hover class on list elements. I put on the containing ordered list element

```
/*
li:hover { 
   cursor: -moz-grab;
   cursor: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur);  
}
*/

sortable:hover { 
   cursor: -moz-grab;
   cursor: url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur);  
}
```